# How do I make 2 or more variable never be equal in Python?

Tags: python, list, variables, random

I'm new at programming and I've heard that one thing to do to improve your programming skills is try to create some projects, just for fun, and I'm trying to create some kind of Q&A game using the random function to shuffle the alternatives (A, B, C, D, E) at each try. Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
import random

list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

n1 = (random.choice(list))
n2 = (random.choice(list))
n3 = (random.choice(list))
n4 = (random.choice(list))
n5 = (random.choice(list))

print("Question 1 - What is the result of 2+2?")

print("A){}.".format(n1))
print("B){}.".format(n2))
print("C){}.".format(n3))
print("D){}.".format(n4))
print("E){}.".format(n5))
```

The output is:

```
Question 1 - What is the result of 2+2?

A)4.
B)1.
C)2.
D)2.
E)4.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I know its barely impossible to make each alternative be different every time with this code, and my question is: ***How can I make sure the alternatives will never be equal?***

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
n1 = (random.choice(list))
n2 = (random.choice(list))
n3 = (random.choice(list))
n4 = (random.choice(list))
n5 = (random.choice(list))
```

To:

```
n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 = random.sample(list, 5)
```

`random.sample` never gives duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shuffle` method from the random module

`shuffle` lets you randomize the list in place

Answer (score 0):

To easily shuffle the alternatives, you can use `random.shuffle`!

```py
import random

list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
random.shuffle(list)

print("Question 1 - What is the result of 2+2?")

print("A){}.".format(list[0]))
print("B){}.".format(list[1]))
print("C){}.".format(list[2]))
print("D){}.".format(list[3]))
print("E){}.".format(list[4]))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say start with something more basic:

random.sample(range(6), 5)

In the example above the output will be 5 numbers 1 - 5 without duplicates.

Your code will be:

```
import random

n1 = random.sample(range(6), 5)

n2 = random.sample(range(6), 5)

n3 = random.sample(range(6), 5)

n4 = random.sample(range(6), 5)

n5 = random.sample(range(6), 5)

print("Question 1 - What is the result of 2+2?")

print('A', n1)

print('B', n2)

print('C', n3)

print('D', n4)

print('E', n5)
```

Comment: That doesn't work, random.sample is returning a list with 5 objects inside... :)

Comment: You might want to use `random.sample(range(6), 1)[0]` instead.